# How would I calculate the longest win streak and best/worst days of the week to play?

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble figuring out the formula for the yellow fields I highlighted in the excel sheet. I'd like to calculate the highlighted area:

1. Best day of the week to play
2. Worst day of the week to play
3. Longest win streak

[image]

Comment: Which result do you expect for 'Best Day of Week' for Pascal. There are 5 possible results.

Answer (score 0):

The below descibes how you can do it for 'Carter', you can then change the formula to return values for "Pascal'.

**1. Best day of the week to play**
I would look into using an index match on the 'Wins by day of the week' section, returning the data in column H, selecting the row based on the MAX value from I16:I22. You'll want to consider what value you want returned if two days have the same no. of wins. You'll need to adjust the ranges, I demo'd it on some random cells on my worksheet:

```
=INDEX(B5:C9,MATCH(MAX(C5:C9),C5:C9,0),1)
```

**2. Worst day of the week to play**
As with the best day, although select the value based on the MIN value in I16:I22. Formula would be as above but change MAX to MIN

**3. Longest win streak**
This will be easier to calculate if you include a streak column for each player, and then you can use a MAX value on the entire column. In the column increment the cell above by 1 if it is a win for that player. If you go down the additional column route you'd need to just have a formula such as:

```
=MAX(B:B)
```

If column B had the winning streak count, you just need to have in the cells the formula in B2, looking to the winning name (Pascal in my instance, you'll need to adjust the cell reference for the column as I can't see your image on this edit page at the moment):

```
=IF(D2="Pascal",B1+1,0)
```

Comment: Hey Shaun I appreciate the answer. 
What does any of that look like in terms of the actual formula I need to plug in?

Comment: Updated the answer with formulas, have a go at it, change the ranges, see what happens, play around some more, make it work... let me know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**For the Longest Win Streak:**

> =ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(E:E="Carter",ROW(E:E)),IF(E:E<>"Carter",ROW(E:E)))))

This was the formula that actually worked.